# Is there a way to limit Console.ReadLine(); answers to variables?

Tags: c#

So I've been making this Console App that simulates a vending machine as just a fun thing to work on and I'm pretty new to C#. I'm trying to make it so that the user cannot type in anything else other than what they want from the vending machine, but I don't know what to do. What they have to type in to get the item is the ItemID which is set as A1, A2, A3, etc. I've tried searching on google and StackOverflow but I can only find answers for how to only allow integers. Please tell me what I can do to make the userChosenProduct only have specific answers. This is my code:

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //s
            int A1 = 5;
            int A2 = 5;
            int A3 = 5;

            int B1 = 6;
            int B2 = 7;
            int B3 = 8;

            int C1 = 2;
            int C2 = 4;
            int C3 = 4;

            int D1 = 7;
            int D2 = 6;
            int D3 = 7;

            int E1 = 2;
            int E2 = 4;
            int E3 = 4;

            string userChosenProduct;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the vending machine.");
            Console.WriteLine("You currently have 15 credits. (c)");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Here is the list of snacks you may get");
            Console.WriteLine("Chips:\n     (5c)Doritos = A1\n     (5c)Lays = A2\n     (5c)Pringles = A3");
            Console.WriteLine("Candy:\n     (6c)KitKat = B1\n     (7c)Gummy Bears = B2\n     (8c)SourPatch Kids");
            Console.WriteLine("Drinks:\n     (2c)Water = C1\n     (4c)Orange Juice = C2\n     (4c)Apple Juice = C3");
            Console.WriteLine("Soft Drinks:\n     (7c)Coca Cola = D1\n     (6c)Pepsi = D2\n     (7c)Mountain Dew = D3");
            Console.WriteLine("Coffee:\n     (3c)Regular Coffee = E1\n     (4c)Latte = E2\n     (4c)Frappucino = E3");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("What would you like on this fine day?");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Product/Item ID:");
            Console.ReadLine();
            userChosenProduct = Console.ReadLine();


            

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Do you know how to use a class and how to create a dictionary?

Comment: No I do not. @Steve

Comment: After the user types in, you need to check if it is present in an array or dictionary, and show error if it is not. You have to code it, since you are having simple console app.

Comment: `Console.In` is a stream. You can read from it, but you get whatever bytes / chars the OS and user decides to give you. The usual approach is to write a loop that keeps trying until the user enters something you can understand.

Answer (score 2):

I think the biggest problem with your approach is that it's very static. It feels like it is a document rather than a program.

## A. What is an item?

I would suggest to capture what an item **is** in a class. For example:

```
public class Item 
{
    public Item(string code, string name, decimal price, string category)
    {
        Code = code;
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
        Category = category;
    }

    public string Code { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public decimal Price { get; set; } 
    public string Category { get; set; } 
}
```

## B. Building the inventory

Now we can capture the inventory in much more programmatic way. For example:

```
var availableItems = new List<Item>();
availableItems.Add(new Item(code: "A1", name: "Tortilla chips", price: 3.45m, category: "Chips"));
availableItems.Add(new Item(code: "A2", name: "Real chips", price: 4, category: "Chips"));
availableItems.Add(new Item(code: "B1", name: "Black", price: 5.5m, category: "Coffee"));
availableItems.Add(new Item(code: "B2", name: "Latte", price: 6.20m, category: "Coffee"));
```

## C. Showing the inventory

Now we can present the inventory in a way that doesn't change if you add new items. For example:

```
var groupped = availableItems.GroupBy( item => item.Category);

foreach(var group in groupped)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{group.Key}:");
    foreach(var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Code}: {item.Name} = {item.Price}");
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Chips:
A1: Tortilla chips = 3.45
A2: Real chips = 4
Coffee:
B1: Black = 5.5
B2: Latte = 6.20
```

## D. Getting the selection

Generally the answer to your question of how to capture only the desired strings (A1, B2, C2, etc.) is that you need to compare the entered string to the codes in your inventory. Here is one way:

```
Item? selection = null;
while (selection == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your selection:");
    var answer = Console.ReadLine();
    selection = availableItems.FirstOrDefault( item => item.Code == answer);
}

Console.WriteLine($"You selected: {selection.Code} which is {selection.Name}");
```